# How to plot a polyline between multiple points with vba

Tags: vba, autocad, polyline

I am trying to plot a polyline between multiple points in vba into autocad. I have almost finished my code, but the thing is that the points may repeat themselves, as 2 lines can have the same starting point, and the points are nor in a sorted way.
I need to be able to addd all points even if they aren't sorted, cause I have to keep the order of the points I am tryint to plot.
I am getting this error:

```
Invalid Procedure or argument call
Set acadPol = acadDoc.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(Points)
```

This is my code:

```
Points(1)=9736.242889: Points(2)=9954.553808
Points(3)=9718.429708: Points(4)=9936.874562


If acadDoc.ActiveSpace = acModelSpace Then
Set acadPol = acadDoc.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(Points)
Else
Set acadPol = acadDoc.PaperSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(Points)
End If
acadPol.Closed = False
acadPol.Update
End If
        End If
```

Comment: Please read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: A lightweight poly line accepts a list of 2d vertices.

Comment: Also, it is possible the coordinates array is zero based indexing. But your code is not complete. You don’t even show us how you have declared  your points array variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete but I notice you have started your coordinates list at index 1.

There are plenty of [examples](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/ex_addlightweightpolyline.htm) on the internet

```
Sub Example_AddLightWeightPolyline()
    ' This example creates a lightweight polyline in model space.

    Dim plineObj As AcadLWPolyline
    Dim points(0 To 9) As Double

    ' Define the 2D polyline points
    points(0) = 1: points(1) = 1
    points(2) = 1: points(3) = 2
    points(4) = 2: points(5) = 2
    points(6) = 3: points(7) = 2
    points(8) = 4: points(9) = 4
    
    ' Create a lightweight Polyline object in model space
    Set plineObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(points)
    ZoomAll

End Sub
```

As you can see, you need to start your coordinates array at index 0 and not 1.

Does this help?